# Wifi batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file so I don't have to keep retyping code whenever I turn on my computer. The code I put in is to make a virtual router with my computer, which makes my computer into a homepass (the software that I normally run is giving me errors, so I have to do it the hard way now).

Anyways, below is the code I normally run in CMD in admin mode.

```
netsh
wlan
stop hostednetwork
set hostednetwork ssid="attwifi"
set hostednetwork key=1234567890
start hostednetwork
```

Whenever I try to run this in a batch file, the file doesn't put in anything after the first command. (It's as if I typed in "netsh" and pressed enter). Is there a way to run this?

On top of that, is there a way I can get the batch file to open up Network Connections? Sometimes I have to tell my computer to share the net from my main WiFi card to the virtual router. Below is a directory to Network Connections
Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections

Also, is there any way to run this batch file when Windows first starts up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A batch file is not just a keyboard macro. It executes the `netsh` command, then *waits for it to exit* before attempting to execute the `wlan` command (which won't work, because it's not a program or command - it's interpreted by the `netsh` program). Batch files can't talk to other programs like that.

Luckily, you can pass commands to `netsh` via its command-line:

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid="attwifi"
:: etc
```

That way, `netsh` executes the command you specify, then exits; and the batch file can move onto the next line.

To open Network Connections, you can execute `control netconnections` (see [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/control-panel-command-line.htm) for details).

To run your batch file on startup, put a shortcut to it (or the file itself) in your Start menu's Startup folder.

Comment: Thanks :D

Is there a way I can get this to start when the computer starts up? Also, is there a way to get this to pull up network Connections in the Control Panel?

Comment: Edited to add answers to those.

Comment: Thanks. One thing I forgot to ask is, is there a way to run the bat as admin mode? The wifi code will not work if CMD isn't in admin mode.

Thanks again

Comment: If you make a shortcut to the bat file, I think you can right-click on it and go to its properties, then check "Run as admin". Then put that shortcut in your startup.

Comment: @user: If the startup folder doesn't work for you, add a scheduled task that starts when the computer boots or when you log on.  Run the program "Task Scheduler", and then click the Action menu and then Create Basic Task.  Once you've created the task, select it and go to its properties for more stuff you can change, including the user credentials that the task will run as.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. I'm going to work on a few other batch files before I restart my computer. (The good news is everything but one of them works.)
Maybe you can take a look at the one that doesn't work and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Below is the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596736/minimize-all-windows-batch-file