# minimize all windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to make my computer more automated on what I normally do when I first turn it on. But, I'm having problems with the minimize batch file. I'm trying to get it where the batch file will wait 5 seconds, and then minimize all open windows. I'm trying the following code.

```
timeout /t 5
nircmd sendkeypress rwin+"d"
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and should be using?

Comment: And what's not working?

Comment: The code isn't minimizing anything.

Comment: That syntax is correct.  Do you have the latest version?  Make sure nircmd.exe is either in the batch file's CWD or in its location is in %PATH%.

Comment: The examples on the [help](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html) page don't have quotes.. Maybe try `nircmd sendkeypress rwin+d`

Comment: I tested it. It worked on my PC. Problem is in something else.

Comment: @Blorgbeard That's the first thing I tried. But, I copy and pasted your code and it still didn't work.

Comment: @user3924790 if you're running this by double-clicking it, try adding `pause` as the last line. The error may be disappearing too quickly to see.

Comment: Why are people voting down this question? This is not a stupid/spam question, and others may have the same problem.

Comment: @Gary You were right. Please answer the question below so I can mark you as being right.

Comment: I am down voting this question because it doesn't clearly state that it is only useful to users of NirSoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax is correct. It would greatly help your question to include error messages.  Since my comment fixed your issue, your error was probably `'nircmd' is not recoognized as an internal or external command...`  To call a file from a batch script, perform one of the following:

- Include the full or relative path to the file
- Make sure it's in the same directory as the batch file
- Include the file's path in the %PATH% variable